# Combining Option Routes in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, block, rest

I'm tring to setup a Route like so:

GET /settings/
PUT /settings/
GET /settings/photos
PUT /settings/photos

This is the routing code that I have setup for it:

```
#I just do this for code reuse
get = { :method => :get }
put = { :method => :put }

pub.settings '/settings', :controller => :settings, :action => :index, :conditions => get
pub.with_options :controller => :settings, :path_prefix => "/settings", :name_prefix => "settings_" do |settings|
  settings.update '', :action => :update, :conditions => put
  settings.photos '/photos', :action => :photos, :conditions => get
  settings.photos_update '/photos', :action => :photos_update, :conditions => :put
end
```

This works, but if you notice that the first route "pub.settings" is outside of the mapped_options block.

If I were todo

```
pub.with_options :controller => :settings, :path_prefix => "/settings", :name_prefix => "settings_" do |settings|
  settings.root '', :action => :index, :conditions => get
  settings.update '', :action => :update, :conditions => put
  settings.photos '/photos', :action => :photos, :conditions => get
  settings.photos_update '/photos', :action => :photos_update, :conditions => :put
end
```

Then I would get (in rake routes) the path to settings would be "settings_root_path" and not "settings_path"

Does anyone know how to include it into the block and still have the routing function name as "settings_path" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has a `:path_prefix`, `:path_names`, and `:name_prefix` that help control how the helpers are generated. The [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) has a few examples that might help.

`:path_names` controls the names being used in restful routes
`:path_prefix` sets the path used when generating helpers.
`:name_prefix` sets the prefix to the name of the generated helpers. This prefix may be set to `nil` or the empty_string.

For your case, I'd try (though untested):

```
settings.root '', :action => :index, :name_prefix => nil, :conditions => get
```

Comment: such definition gives an error 
settings.root :action => :index, :name_prefix => nil, :conditions => get gives root_path but not settings_path

Answer (score 1):

```
 settings.settings  '', :action => :index, :conditions => get, :name_prefix => ''
```